# Chinese ellipsis marks

Tags: traditional-characters, simplified-characters, punctuation

How is an ellipsis 省略号 written in Chinese?

`。。。`

`...`

or

`......`

The only reference I can find on this is [this word reference forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/punctuation-ellipsis-%E7%9C%81%E7%95%A5%E5%8F%B7%E3%80%80.1611958/) which states `......`. [This](https://zhongruige.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/the-art-of-punctuation-in-chinese/) also says 6 dots.

E.g.,

`在這裡輸入您的訊息......` （Type your message here...）

Comment: similar question asked again only 8 days ago: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23859/punctuation-omiting-part-of-a-quote  repetition of earlier answer earned another 7X10 points

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Six dots.

It is called [刪節號](http://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/FILES/SITE_CONTENT/M0001/HAU/h11.htm) in Taiwan, and [省略号](http://www.zdic.net/appendix/f3.htm) in China. Both use 6 dots.

Comment: Is it 6 periods or 2 "ellipsis marks" that take up the space of two characters?

Comment: [U+2026 ……](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)
In Chinese, the ellipsis is six dots (in two groups of three dots, occupying the same horizontal or vertical space as two characters).

Answer (score 0):

the formal type is ……and somtimes we use ... or 。。。to express the same meaning

Answer (score 0):

All are wrong. Three dots "…" is one single character in Chinese font, like the comment by @SLS under his answer. It's not correct to written to six English dots, or three Chinese period marks.

Answer (score -1):

The last one is right，we use 6 dots in china，“。。。”is just three “。” sometimes will be used to have a chat online