# Punctuation - Omiting part of a quote

Tags: punctuation

In my native language we use '(...)' to indicate that part of the quote was omitted. For example, in the paragraph below I would like to omit the bolded part, how should I write it?

"在波兰，我们充分了解这样的一体化过程所带来的益处。**波兰2004年加入欧洲联盟。欧盟已为一个历史上长久遭受冲突和战争之苦的欧洲大陆带来了繁荣和稳定，给包括波兰在内欧洲国家提供了一个良好的发展环境以及许多的发展机遇。**因此，我们欢迎中国为加强东亚与欧洲之间的经济纽带，并为了沿一带一路的国家创造新的发展机遇所提出的倡议。"

If it was Polish, it would look like this:

"在波兰，我们充分了解这样的一体化过程所带来的益处。(...)因此，我们欢迎中国为加强东亚与欧洲之间的经济纽带，并为了沿一带一路的国家创造新的发展机遇所提出的倡议。"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: same in Chinese：省略号（……） https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/219404997.html

Comment: There are two kinds of ellipsis in Chinese …… and ⋯⋯ .

Answer (score 7):

"在波兰，我们充分了解这样的一体化过程所带来的益处。……因此，我们欢迎中国为加强东亚与欧洲之间的经济纽带，并为了沿一带一路的国家创造新的发展机遇所提出的倡议。"

[It is called 刪節號 in Taiwan, and 省略号 in China. Both use 6 dots.](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23238/chinese-ellipsis-marks/23240?s=1|0.5265#23240)

[In Chinese, the ellipsis is six dots (in two groups of three dots, occupying the same horizontal or vertical space as two characters).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

Comment: Thank you, I knew about the ellipsis mark but did not think it could be used in this case.

Comment: @KatarzynaSerafin I never see this usage in Mandrain. '*' mark are more likely used as "attention, we have a clarification down below" rather than omitting. Probably I'm wrong. (I am a native Chinese, have been in China mainland 20 years)