# How to type the Chinese ellipsis ⋯⋯ using Google Pinyin IME?

Tags: punctuation, input-methods

I've learned that  "。。。" is incorrect in Chinese punctuation (see e.g. [Chinese ellipsis marks](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23238/chinese-ellipsis-marks)), it should be "⋯⋯", called 省略号.  I've just been copy/pasting this into my documents so far, but there's surely a better way to do this.

I'm using Google Pinyin IME which is fairly standard, I think.  (If relevant, my operating system is Linux Mint.)

**Question**: How to type the Chinese ellipsis ⋯⋯ using Google Pinyin IME?

I didn't find an obvious answer by searching [`google pinyin ellipsis`](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20pinyin%20ellipsis).

Comment: Can you type unicode characters? Hold down `alt` and type `0133` then release `alt`: ……

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer.  I recall that working on Windows, so it might be an operating system difference.

Comment: What does Shift+6 produce?

Comment: Hey!  Shift+6 works!!  ………………………… Thanks, although it should be an answer.

Comment: I'll add an answer ...

Comment: Google IME only support Windows (killed by Google already), and Android (still available). Do you mean `fcitx-googlepinyin`?

Comment: Ah, yes that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Google pinyin on Linux, but a lot of (simplified) Chinese IME use `Shift + 6` to produce ellipsis. I assume the Google pinyin might follow the trend.

And by the way, you can try all the symbol keys on the keyboard with the Chinese IME. They do not always produce the "full-width" version of the symbol on the keyboard. Some Chinese specific punctuations can be inputted in this way.